# HTML - Identifying problems with my auto playing slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help trying to fix my auto-playing slideshow. Instead of displaying the slideshow, it just displays the images vertically. Neither the arrow buttons or dots are working either.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
    <img src="slideshow/img1.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
    <img src="slideshow/img2.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
    <img src="slideshow/img3.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
    <img src="slideshow/img4.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>

</div>
</div> <!--end of "slideshow" -->
```

**JS**

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 3000);
```

Here is the result (zoomed out so you can get an overview):

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: where is the css?

Comment: Please edit your post and add your code here in your post. Also please create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and provide the link of your fiddle in your post so we can see the problem and help you on it...

Comment: Apologies. Here's the link to the jsFiddle with all code. https://jsfiddle.net/xooa4vo5/

Comment: You logic seem a little weird! Why don't you use one of the free ready to use plugins online?

Comment: It's for a HTML project in class, pure code, no plugins.